# Convert Number and Text to Number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, regexextract

I have a [spreadsheet in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APNV_585aty75wJ3JyJDatXJ-qGvbiYvy2PVm5FSrNg/edit#gid=0) with data like this:
In sheet 2, in column pricelist, the below data is there. I want the summary in sheet 1 to have the same. I have used `index` and `match` but it is not working.

```
$100 in text
102 in Number
$103 in text
104 in number
105 in number
```

When I do the `vlookup` and try to multiply with 1 it is showing an error. I don't understand how to make the change.

I have used this formula to convert text to numbers, but if the cell has a number format then it is showing an error.

The formula used to convert text to numbers:

```
=roundup(REGEXREPLACE(index(Sheet1!A:A,match(E3,Sheet1!A:A,0),""),"[$,*]",),)
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1APNV_585aty75wJ3JyJDatXJ-qGvbiYvy2PVm5FSrNg/edit#gid=0

Comment: shared once again with access

Comment: did you even try the solution I suggested you?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pF-5VX2LbjTixohl_VZoQ6Iu-pRKkxuGP_9rDK7Owk8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

- to convert text to numbers use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+"), ",", ".")), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

- for non-US syntax try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A); "\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+"); "."; ",")); ))
```

[image: 5]

---

- if you are not sure which syntax to use, take this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A); "\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+"); ","; "."));
 VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A); "\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+|\d+"); "."; ","))); ))
```

Comment: If i am using index and match to the same and getting the data from one more sheet how to include the same in the formula.

Comment: @VinayChandrashekhar **[ask a new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or [edit your current question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/126377/edit)** to include what issue you have and what's your desired output. otherwise, mark the question as solved & upvote if this helped you - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)